# Do layout engines publish events?

Tags: html, events, layout

Is there a way  to listen to layout engine events ?  , something like "finished_rendering_element" or something of that sort ? , i.e. : i want to be informed when a div with an id of "mydiv" has been rendered ? i could do that by including a settimout in the top of the page and testing the dom and execute approximately at the time it is avaliable but i was wondering if there is a better way ?

Answer (score 1):

I am not aware of any JavaScript interfaces or events on this level being exposed by any browser.

And probably rightly so: I can hardly think of scenarios where such fine-grained event control would make real-world sense.

It is possible to place `<script>` tags after an element:

```
<a id="my_link">Link</a>
<script>....</script>
```

you can safely assume that the `a` element is available to you in the script.

Other than that, you are left with the `DOMReady` and `load` events.

Comment: the real world scenario is when you are injected to the page by a tag , i.e. : i don't have control of the page only markers on the page where i should live ... so i can't put a script after the container only at the top where if i do so then i have to test when the element is ready or at the bottom but then i might be wasting time or causing some sort of flickering event if i change the content of the container ...

Comment: @amnon can you make an example? There might well be a solution for your use case that works some other way